# SQL -VB - Does it evaluate the else even when the if is true?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to prevent #error being displayed in a report I am creating

This happens when I divide 2 numbers and one of them is zero

So I tried using an if/switch statement to check if either of the 2 number are 0 before doing the divide :

```
    =IIf(Fields!Field1.Value = 0 
            or Fields!Field2.Value = 0 
            or Not(IsNumeric(Fields!Field1.Value)) 
            or Not(IsNumeric(Fields!Field2.Value)), 
        0, 
        (Fields!Field1.Value/Fields!Field2.Value)*100
    )


    =Switch(
            Fields!Field1.Value = 0 or Fields!Fields.Value = 0, 0,
            IsNumeric(Fields!Field1.Value) or IsNumeric(Fields!Fields.Value), (Fields!Field1.Value/Fields!Fields.Value)*100
    )
```

Both of these still throw the error. It seems that the else condition is still evaluated even if the if statement is true

If I change the code to just print X or Y for the if and else, then it works - so there isn't an error in the if statement

This sems ridiculous to me

Please tell me I am doing something wrong? I can't believe the language would evaluate the else when the if is true

**EDIT**

So it seems that the else condition is evaluated. So how do you get around a potential divide by zero error?

here's the answer taken from :
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic442497-150-1.aspx#bm1115960

Another option (especially if you've got a report with many expressions that could result in divide by zero situations is to use a Custom Code function.

In the Code tab/window of Report Properties, enter something like the following:

```
Public Function DivideBy(ByVal Exp1, ByVal Exp2)
If Exp2 = 0 Then
DivideBy = 0
Else : DivideBy = Exp1 / Exp2
End If
End Function
```

Then insert the expression
=code.DivideBy(Field!ToBeDivided.Value,Field!DividingBy.Value)
into any cell that has the potential for divide by zero problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both the true and false parts of an IIf function get evaluated:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf#Side_Effects

> **Side Effects**
>   Another issue with IIf arises because it is a library
>   function: unlike the C-derived conditional operator, both truepart and
>   the falsepart will be evaluated regardless of which one is actually
>   returned. Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> value = 10 
> result = IIf(value = 10, TrueFunction, FalseFunction)
> ```
>
> Although TrueFunction is the function intended to be called, IIf will
>   cause both TrueFunction and FalseFunction to be executed.
>
> Also consider this one:
>
> ```
> a = 10 
> b = 0 
> result = IIf(b <> 0, a / b, 0)
> ```
>
> While the programmer
>   intends to avoid raising an error by performing a division by zero,
>   whenever b is zero the error will actually happen. This is because the
>   code in the snippet is to be read as
>
> ```
> a = 10 b = 0
> _temp1 = a / b ' Error if b = 0
> _temp2 = 0
> _temp3 = b <> 0 result = IIf(_temp3, _temp1 , _temp2)
> ```
>
> This issue makes
>       the IIf() call less useful than the conditional operator. To solve
>   this issue, Microsoft developers had considered converting IIf to
>   an intrinsic function; had this happened, the compiler would have been
>   able to perform type inference and short-circuiting by replacing the
>   function call with inline code.

Comment: wow - I'm stunned. So what would be the best way to prevent a divide by zero error ?

Answer (score 6):

Both `Iif()` and `Switch()` are function calls, so any parameters passed to them will be evaluated. They do not have the ability to short-circuit.

Comment: is there an alternative I could use to prevent a divide by zero error?

Comment: I don't see why your `IIf()` is producing `#Error`. You really only need to check the divisor - `Field2.Value` - anyway. Possible that the value is `Nothing`?

Comment: no, afraid not, the 2 values are displayed in the report elsewhere and I can see that one of them is zero and one of them is a decimal amount.

Answer (score 3):

`IIF` is a function, and all the arguments to a function are evaluated before being the function itself is evaluated.

To prevent this issue, you will need to use a full `If/Else` statement.

Also related, if you're used to short-circuit evaluation of your boolean expressions (eg `&&` in C-derived languages) you need to use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in VB.Net.

Comment: AndAlso and OrElse won't help here - they help to stop later parts of the condition from evaluating, but here the issue is that the second (else) part of the result is being evaluated.

Comment: Good point, I meant in the context of a normal IF statement... :(

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an IIF statement in VB, I think everything gets evaluated, irrespective of the initial condition. This is something that has to be worked around in IIF statements.

In the second statement, the `Fields!Field**2**.Value` from the first IIF statement has become `Fields!Field**s**.Value`. Its possible that the error in that statement is failing because of that as `.Value` will cause an error if `Fields!Fields` is nothing

Comment: no - I just manually changed the field names for posting on here to disguise our company name - just made a typo in doing so

Comment: Fair enough. Wasn't going to say anything about it being a dodgy naming convention! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this error in RS 2005 and I can't! I took the following dataset:

```
select 5 as field1, 0 as field2
union
select 10 as field1, 5 as field2
union
select null as field1, 5 as field2
union 
select 3 as field1, null as field2
union 
select null as field1, null as field2
union 
select 0 as field1, null as field2
union
 select null as field1,  0 as field2
union
 select 11 as field1, 10 as field2
union
 select PI() as field1, 0 as field2
union
select PI() as field1, PI() as field2
```

and used your expressions, with Jon Egerton's correction in the switch. I then did a pure no-checked division.

Both your expressions worked, and even when I divide by 0 I get "Infinity" or "Nan", but not #Error.

What happens if you replace your division by 1/0. Do you get #Error or do you get Infinity?

[image: Report Preview]